# Effect of temporary variable on erasing the background of a GroupBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pinvoke

**The context:**

Consider drawing a `GroupBox` with a gradient as a part of it's background.

*Example:*

[image: Ideal <code>GroupBox</code>]

---

Let's perform the following actions:

- Create a `class` that inherits `GroupBox`.

  - Set it's `FlatStyle` `property` to `FlatStyle.System`.
  - `override` it's `WndProc` method.
  - Handle the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, in which we *draw the gradient*.
  - Handle the `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message, where we call `DefWndProc` and `return`.
    <sub>*(Will be needed later.)*</sub>
- Add a `Label` as it's child `Control`.
  <sub>*(The* `Label`*'s background must be transparent to be able to see the gradient behind it's* `Text`*.*</sub>

  - Create a `class` that inherits `Label`.
  - `override` the `WndProc` method.
  - "*Simulate transparency*" by calling the `DrawThemeParentBackground` function to draw the `GroupBox`'s background on the `Label`'s `Graphics`.

**The issue:**

> Depending on whether a temporary variable is used to hold the `Graphics` `object`, the end result varies, depicted with the code sample and image below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MCVE
{
    class GroupBox : System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    {
        const int WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x14;
        const int WM_PRINTCLIENT = 0x318;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_ERASEBKGND:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    using (var g = Graphics.FromHdc(m.WParam))//CASE 1
                    //using (var e = new PaintEventArgs(Graphics.FromHdc(m.WParam), ClientRectangle))//CASE 2
                    {
                        var e = new PaintEventArgs(g, ClientRectangle);//CASE 1
                        var r = new Rectangle(2, 12, Width - 4, Height - 2);
                        using (var b = new LinearGradientBrush(r, BackColor, SystemColors.Window, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, r);//Draw the gradient.
                        }
                    }
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(1);//Signal that no further drawing of the background is necessary by WM_PAINT.
                    return;
                case WM_PRINTCLIENT:
                    DefWndProc(ref m);//Bypass GroupBox's internal handling so that actual painting is handled by Windows.
                    return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);//Default processing of the rest of the messages.
        }
    };

    class Label : System.Windows.Forms.Label
    {
        const int WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x14;
        const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern IntPtr BeginPaint(IntPtr hWnd, out PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern IntPtr EndPaint(IntPtr hWnd, ref PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);
        //Ask Windows to send a message to the parent to draw it's background in the current device context.
        [DllImport("uxtheme.dll")] extern static int DrawThemeParentBackground(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdc, ref Rectangle pRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct PAINTSTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr hdc;
            public bool fErase;
            public Rectangle rcPaint;
            public bool fRestore;
            public bool fIncUpdate;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)] public byte[] rgcReserved;
        };

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_ERASEBKGND:
                    var r = ClientRectangle;
                    DrawThemeParentBackground(Handle, m.WParam, ref r);
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(1);//Signal that no further drawing of the background is necessary by WM_PAINT.
                    return;
                case WM_PAINT:
                    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                    var hdc = BeginPaint(Handle, out ps);
                    EndPaint(Handle, ref ps);//Don't paint any text so that the gradient remains visible.
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                    return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);//Default processing of the rest of the messages.
        }
    };

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread] static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var form = new Form() { BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight };
            var groupbox = new GroupBox() { Anchor = (AnchorStyles)15, FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System, Location = new Point(10, 10), Text = "groupBox1" };

            form.Controls.Add(groupbox);
            groupbox.Controls.Add(new Label() { FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System, Location = new Point(50, 50) });

            Application.Run(form);
        }
    };
}
```

Running the above MCVE *(CASE 1)* produces the expected ouput as shown in the example image.

On commenting out the lines remarked *CASE 1* and uncommenting the line marked *CASE 2* gives the following undesired output:

[image: Actual <code>GroupBox</code>]

**The question:**

Why does the removal of the temporary variable produce such a vastly different output?

Comment: The problem is not the variable, but what gets disposed by the `using` block. All I can say is that in the CASE 2 the graphics object is not disposed (since the `PaintEventArgs` is not owning it), which probably has side effects.

Comment: DrawThemeParentBackground() is implemented by sending the parent the WM_ERASEBKGRND + WM_PRINTCLIENT message.  The case2 bug is the 2nd argument to the PaintEventArgs constructor, wrong rectangle.  The clip rectangle is already selected properly by DrawThemeParentBackground() and it is relative from the label.  Which ensures only the part of the parent overlapped by the label gets drawn.  Another bug is the pinvoke declaration for DrawThemeParentBackground, 3rd argument is RECT, not Rectangle.

Comment: @IvanStoev The `Graphics` `object` implements `IDisposable` and will get disposed once the `using` block terminates. The `PaintEventArgs` simply calls dispose on the `Graphics` `object` if it is placed in the `using` block instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I know about the `RECT` part, I simply ommitted it in the MCVE. Also, I am creating the same `PaintEventArgs` in `CASE 2` as well. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar No, it doesn't. Again, CASE 1 `using` block disposes the `Graphics` object. While CASE 2 `using` block disposes the `PaintEventArgs` object which **does not** dispose the `Graphics` object.

Comment: @IvanStoev Just checked the .NET source. It seems `PaintEventArgs` only disposes `Graphics` `object`s created internally by passing a DC. Thanks, I need to clean up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer for the sake of completeness.

- As pointed out by [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev), the **non-owning** `PaintEventArgs` **does not** call `Dispose` on the `Graphics` `object`.
- This has *visible side effects* as the DC is **reused** by Windows in the `WM_PRINTCLIENT` `Message`, that is sent next to the `WndProc`.

Manually calling `Dispose` on the `Graphics` `object` confirms this.

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromHdc(m.WParam))
{
    using (var e = new PaintEventArgs(g, ClientRectangle))
    {
        var r = new Rectangle(2, 12, Width - 4, Height - 2);
        using (var b = new LinearGradientBrush(r, BackColor, SystemColors.Window, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, r);//Draw the gradient.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can all this boil down to a simple derived class, without PInvoking?
This class derives from `GroupBox`, set it as Transparent using [CreateParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.createparams?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) [CreateParams.ExStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.createparams.exstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams.ExStyle);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) proeprty, enables support for Transparent colors with [Control.SetStyle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetStyle);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) and `ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor` style (this way you can better control the effect of the [LinearGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush.%2523ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2)) and overrides the [OnPaintBackground()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaintbackground?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) method to perform the painting.

It's just a basic example, but it can be tweaked in any other way and still be more portable.
You can drop any control on it.

```
class GradientGroupBox : GroupBox
{
    private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
    public GradientGroupBox() => this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        Color gradFillTo = Color.FromArgb(200, SystemColors.Window);
        Color gradFillFrom = Color.FromArgb(128, this.Parent.BackColor);
        using (LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, gradFillFrom, gradFillTo, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(gradientBrush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams parameters = base.CreateParams;
            parameters.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return parameters;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: GradientGroupBox]